# Counting Falses before Trues in R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to use R to find the average number of attempts before a success in a dataframe with 300,000+ rows. Data is structured as below.

```
EventID  SubjectID  ActionID  Success  DateUpdated
a        b          c         TRUE     2014-06-21 20:20:08.575032+00
b        a          c         FALSE    2014-06-20 02:58:40.70699+00
```

I'm still learning my way through R. It looks like I can use ddply to separate the frame out based on Subject and Action (I want to see how many times a given subject tries an action before achieving a success), but I can't figure out how to write the formula I need to apply.

Comment: Check out the `rle()` function in basic R. You can find the length of "runs" (say, runs of FALSE before a TRUE is encountered).

Comment: For each combination of `SubjectID` and `ActionID`, are there multiple records of `Success == TRUE`, or only records for up to and including their first success for that action? Also, it will be easier for people to answer your question if you post a larger sample of your data (try using `dput()` on a subset of your data).

Comment: @TARehman That looks super useful.

Unfortunately, it's proprietary data associated with my workplace, so I can't share the actual data.

Comment: @nrussell There are multiple records of Success == TRUE  and Success == FALSE; attempts don't stop after a success, and one success doen't guarantee future success.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)

# example data
dt = data.table(group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2), success = c(F,F,T,F,T,F,T))
#   group success
#1:     1   FALSE
#2:     1   FALSE
#3:     1    TRUE
#4:     1   FALSE
#5:     1    TRUE
#6:     2   FALSE
#7:     2    TRUE

dt[, which(success)[1] - 1, by = group]
#   group V1
#1:     1  2
#2:     2  1
```

Replace `group` with `list(subject, action)` or whatever is appropriate for your data (after converting it to `data.table` from `data.frame`).

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on Tarehman's suggestion, since I like `rle`,

```
foo <-  rle(data$Success)

mean(foo$lengths[foo$values==FALSE])
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an answer to a totally different question, but does this get close to what you want?

```
tfs <- sample(c(FALSE,TRUE),size = 50, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8,0.2))

tfs_sums <- cumsum(!tfs)
repsums <- tfs_sums[duplicated(tfs_sums)]
mean(repsums - c(0,repsums[-length(repsums)]))

tfs
     [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[39] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

repsums
1  6  8  9 20 20 20 20 24 26 31 36

repsums - c(0,repsums[-length(repsums)])
1  5  2  1 11  0  0  0  4  2  5  5
```

The last vector shown is the length of each continuous "run" of FALSE values in the vector `tfs`

Answer (score 1):

you could use data.table work around to get what you need as follows:

`library (data.table)`

```
  df=data.frame(EventID=c("a","b","c","d"),SubjectID=c("b","a","a","a"),ActionID=c("c","c","c","c"),Success=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE))
```

`dt=data.table(df)`

```
dt[ , Index := 1:.N , by = c("SubjectID" , "ActionID","Success") ]
```

Now this Index column will hold the number that you need for each subject/action consecutive experiments. You need to aggregate to get that number (max number)

```
result=stats:::aggregate.formula(Index~(SubjectID+ActionID),data=dt,FUN= function(x) max(x))
```

so this will give you the max index and it is the number of the falses before you hit a true. Note that you might need to do further processing to filter out subjects that has never had a true